# How to add column to Yii2 query builder result which could be used to order by?

Tags: php, sql, parameters, yii2, query-builder

I have a Yii2 query object which contains this method to execute fulltext search

```
public function search($search)
{
    return $this->andWhere('MATCH(title, description, tags) AGAINST(:search) AS value', ['search' => $search])
        ->orderBy('value');
}
```

The whole code looks like

```
$dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
    'query' => Video::find()->published()->search($search)
]);
```

Of course this does not work cause andWhere() does not allow AS value statement. Can somebody tell me please how to solve this problem? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Can you post the complete query builder code, how  you are attaching this scope to your main query and what is in your select() clause

Comment: You can use active record's [select()](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/db-query-builder#select) method but i am not sure how to bind value of `$search` in select clause

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you can include your search part in your select clause in order to perform sorting on results

```
Video::find()
     ->published()
     ->search($search)
     ->select(['*','MATCH(title, description, tags) AGAINST(:search) AS value'])
     ->orderBy('value');
```

But the problem is to bind the value for `:search` placeholder (not sure about that), For this I guess you can use [`yii\db\Expression`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-db-expression) class which takes params as second argument and this expression can be used in [`select()`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-db-query#select()-detail) method, So now the query builder will look something like

```
Video::find()
     ->published()
     ->search($search)
     ->select(['*',
         new \yii\db\Expression('MATCH(title, description, tags) AGAINST(:search) AS value',['search' => $search])
     ])
     ->orderBy('value');
```

Soution is the params method:

```
$this->select(['*','MATCH(title, description, tags) AGAINST(:search) AS score'])
    ->andWhere('MATCH(title, description, tags) AGAINST(:search)', ['search' => $search])
    ->params(['search' => $search])
    ->orderBy(['score' => SORT_DESC]);
```

Comment: I have it. There is a method named params() which accepts array of params. No need to do it via Expression()

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use "value" then you have to write it in select statement. You can apply filter on result using "having" clause.

You can use any methods from below two

1.

```
$query = Product::find()
    ->andWhere('MATCH ('.Product::tableName().'.name) AGAINST(:q)'
    ->params(['q' => $this->q])
    ->orderBy('(MATCH ('.Product::tableName().'.name) AGAINST(:q)) DESC');
```

2

```
$query = Product::find();
    ->select(Product::tableName().'.*, MATCH ('.Product::tableName().'.name) AGAINST(:q) as VL')
    ->having('VL > 5')
    ->params(['q' => $this->q]);
```

Comment: I need to do it in Yii2 flow.

Comment: I have updated my answer with sample code, please check.

Comment: It seems orderBy does not accept expressions like this. But you mentioned params() method which solves the problem. Thank you.